# spring mvc and freemarker - how to post a form ?

Tags: forms, spring-mvc, freemarker

I am unsure about doing simple crud operation with spring and freemarker.This is what I tried to do.

springTag.ftl

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

  <html xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" >

 <head>
 ......
 <#import "/spring.ftl" as spring />
 ..........

 <head>
  ......


 </head>

  <body>

  <@fragment.header/>


   <form action="/listController/springTag" method="post" >
    <@spring.bind "student" />
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Name:</td>
                                    <td><input path="student.name"  /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Age:</td>
                                    <td><input path="student.age"  /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                      ........................

                            </body>
```

How do I get the values in controller ? I have specified the model attribute as `student` . I am a newbee here .  Can someone help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
<form action="/listController/springTag" method="post" >
                        <@spring.bind path= "student" />
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Name:</td>
                                    <td>  <@spring.formInput "student.name" /> </td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td>Age:</td>
                                    <td><@spring.formInput "student.age" />
                                    <@spring.showErrors "student.age","error" /></td>
                                </tr>

                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="2">
                                        <input type="submit" value="Save Changes" />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </form>
```

This was the change I made.